# Sum each row of an array and print all in descending order

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Given a two dimensional array I would like to sum all the elements of each row and then print the results in descending order. Below you can see what I have come up with so far.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Collections;

public class array_PA3{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[][] hoursArray = {   

            {2,3,3,4,5,8,8,0},
            {7,4,4,3,3,4,4,0},
            {3,4,3,3,3,2,2,0},
            {9,4,7,7,3,4,1,0},
            {3,4,3,3,6,3,8,0},
            {3,4,6,3,3,4,4,0},
            {3,4,8,8,3,8,4,0},
            {6,5,9,9,2,7,9,0}};

        int maxRow = 0;
        int indexRow = 0;
        int [] totalRow = new int[8];

        for (int row = 0; row <= 7; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column <= 7; column++){
                totalRow[row] += hoursArray[row][column];
            }      
            System.out.println("The sum of row " + row + " is " + totalRow[row] + ".");     
        } 
        Arrays.sort(totalRow, Collections.reverseOrder());       
    }   
}
```

Comment: 1. Fix the formatting - this code is unreadable and no one will take that much effort to help you. 2. I can't see the question, neither explanation of expected/actual behaviour of the code you added. 3. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Formatting fixed for you (I think) but you still need to add text to your question as per @JaroslawPawlak's comment above. All we're asking is for just a little effort on your part to make your question understandable.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. always include what the code is doing and how that deviates from what you were expecting. People don't want to create a new project in their IDE and execute your code just to see what is going wrong ;)

Answer (score 0):

your totalRow is an int[]:

```
    int[] totalRow = new int[8];
```

That causes the error:

```
Caught: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Collections$ReverseComparator cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
```

Which is actually complaining because when you have a primitive type array like int[], because it is primitive it doesn't implement the required Comparable interface.

Change the line to the following, which will solve your problem because the int's will be 'auto-boxed' to Integer, which does implement Comparable

```
    Integer[] totalRow = new int[8];
```

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

And: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html